# iptables string matching feasability; possible use with fail2ban

Tags: iptables, load-balancing, fail2ban, http-headers, cdn

We have several Apache 2.4 web servers behind a load balancer and CDN front end - where HTTPS is terminated - we see the client IP in headers from the front end in the back end Apache logs. I'm wondering if it's feasible to use iptables' string matching (on the web server machines) to block IPs based on a particular header only, i.e. the one with client ip inside?

Our Linux kernel is recent and our iptables kernel module has been compiled with: CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_STRING=m.

I've read it can be CPU intensive and perhaps have unintended consequences if the string match matches beyond the particular header containing the client ip. Or that there are better tools to achieve this, like a proxy, but I would still like to know more about the experiences of others using iptables' string match capability with Apache and perhaps fail2ban.

Ideally Apache would have something like nginx's 444. I'm able to give IPs 403s [based on matching the IP in a header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76190114/apache-2-4-rewritecond-with-expr-ipmatch-on-variable-other-than-remote-addr), but a 444 connection drop seems lower level (more abrupt/desireable) and less resource intense vs a 403; I wonder though - is it? Maybe a 444 is more resource intensive vs a 403?

Thanks for any insights!

Comment: I think the best solution here is to use a different fail2ban action than iptables (this also allows for TLS termination on the webserver). While this would be simple with nginx or haproxy, I can't think of a method that would work in Apache without doing a lot of research.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy solution when your fail2ban and associated logic is running on the back end servers.

I’d think the first step would be to use Apache [mod_remoteip](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_remoteip.html) ; then the Apache logs on the backend server will contain the actual client IP’s rather then the IP-address of your front end / your load balancer:

> Apache by default identifies the useragent with the connection's `client_ip` value, and the connection `remote_host` and `remote_logname` are derived from this value. These fields play a role in authentication, authorization and logging and other purposes by other loadable modules.
>
> mod_remoteip overrides the client IP of the connection with the advertised useragent IP as provided by a proxy or load balancer, for the duration of the request. A load balancer might establish a long lived keepalive connection with the server, and each request will have the correct useragent IP, even though the underlying client IP address of the load balancer remains unchanged.

Then you can easily run fail2ban against the Apache log files to identify offending IP’s

You will then need a *custom* and suitable fail2ban **ban action** that, when issued from a backend server, will block the offending IP. That can be for example an API call to the firewall in front of your front end that adds the offending IP to a block list or whatever.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'm already able to see the client IP in my back end Apache logs. I'm using a CustomLog format which includes it. The front end passes client IP inside a header and CustomLog includes this in the logs as the actual client IP. Is there still a need for mod_remoteip? It seems to have much more functionality but I already have acutal client IP in my logs, as a separate field, though it also includes a port, e.g. 127.0.0.1:12345. As far as fail2ban blocking via an API call to a front end firewall, I'm interested in using iptables string match to block the IP locally.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the flow of how this would work but I imagine iptables with string match could match connections that also have a particular client IP in a header (passed by the front end); even though iptables might strictly see the IP as belonging to the load balancer - it would differentiate and block based on the contents of the client IP header, passed from the front end.